# Remove encoded html with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, ngsanitize

i have a problem in removing html code from a text with the ng-bind-html option of angularjs.

My text originally is like this:

```
'&lt;p&gt;&lt;!--[if gte mso 9]&gt;&lt;xml&gt; &lt;w:WordDocument&gt;  &lt;w:View&gt;Normal&lt;/w:View&gt;  &lt;w:Zoom&gt;0&lt;/w:Zoom&gt;  &lt;w:HyphenationZone&gt;14&lt;/w:HyphenationZone&gt;  &lt;w:PunctuationKerning/&gt;  &lt;w:ValidateAgainstSchemas/&gt;  &lt;w:SaveIfXMLInvalid&gt;false&lt;/w:SaveIfXMLInvalid&gt;  &lt;w:IgnoreMixedContent&gt;false&lt;/w:IgnoreMixedContent&gt;  &lt;w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText&gt;false&lt;/w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText&gt;  &lt;w:Compatibility&gt;   &lt;w:BreakWrappedTables/&gt;   &lt;w:SnapToGridInCell/&gt;   &lt;w:WrapTextWithPunct/&gt;   &lt;w:UseAsianBreakRules/&gt;   &lt;w:DontGrowAutofit/&gt;  &lt;/w:Compatibility&gt;  &lt;w:BrowserLevel&gt;MicrosoftInternetExplorer4&lt;/w:BrowserLevel&gt; &lt;/w:WordDocument&gt;&lt;/xml&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;!--[if gte mso 9]&gt;&lt;xml&gt; &lt;w:LatentStyles DefLockedState=&quot;false&quot; LatentStyleCount=&quot;156&quot;&gt; &lt;/w:LatentStyles&gt;&lt;/xml&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;&lt;!--[if gte mso 10]&gt;&lt;style&gt; /* Style Definitions */ table.MsoNormalTable {mso-style-name:&quot;Tabella normale&quot;; mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0; mso-tstyle-colband-size:0; mso-style-noshow:yes; mso-style-parent:&quot;&quot;; mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; mso-para-margin:0cm; mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt; mso-pagination:widow-orphan; font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;; mso-ansi-language:#0400; mso-fareast-language:#0400; mso-bidi-language:#0400;}&lt;/style&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt; &lt;span mso-fareast-language:=&quot;&quot; new=&quot;&quot; style=&quot;font-size:10.0pt;line-height:115%;font-family:FuturaStd-Book;mso-fareast-font-family:&quot; times=&quot;&quot;&gt;&#39;il senso del progetto riguarda soprattutto la costruzione di se stessi&rsquo;. il progetto &egrave; per ag fronzoni il punto di partenza e di arrivo della sua ricerca, non &egrave; solo la realizzazione di un manufatto, ma &egrave; un processo di trasformazione dell&rsquo;ambiente umano e dei suoi strumenti che pu&ograve; condizionare l&rsquo;intera vita di un individuo.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;'
```

But this is the result:

```
<p><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <w:WordDocument> <w:View>Normal</w:View> <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom> <w:HyphenationZone>14</w:HyphenationZone> <w:PunctuationKerning/> <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas/> <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid> <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent> <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText> <w:Compatibility> <w:BreakWrappedTables/> <w:SnapToGridInCell/> <w:WrapTextWithPunct/> <w:UseAsianBreakRules/> <w:DontGrowAutofit/> </w:Compatibility> <w:BrowserLevel>MicrosoftInternetExplorer4</w:BrowserLevel> </w:WordDocument></xml><![endif]--></p><p><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <w:LatentStyles DefLockedState="false" LatentStyleCount="156"> </w:LatentStyles></xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 10]><style> /* Style Definitions */ table.MsoNormalTable {mso-style-name:"Tabella normale"; mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0; mso-tstyle-colband-size:0; mso-style-noshow:yes; mso-style-parent:""; mso-padding-alt:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; mso-para-margin:0cm; mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt; mso-pagination:widow-orphan; font-size:10.0pt; font-family:"Times New Roman"; mso-ansi-language:#0400; mso-fareast-language:#0400; mso-bidi-language:#0400;}</style><![endif]--> <span mso-fareast-language:="" new="" style="font-size:10.0pt;line-height:115%;font-family:FuturaStd-Book;mso-fareast-font-family:" times="">'il senso del progetto riguarda soprattutto la costruzione di se stessi’. il progetto è per ag fronzoni il punto di partenza e di arrivo della sua ricerca, non è solo la realizzazione di un manufatto, ma è un processo di trasformazione dell’ambiente umano e dei suoi strumenti che può condizionare l’intera vita di un individuo.</span></p>
```

Here it is a jsfiddle representing my issue: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6j4Lg/155/)

What can i do?

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? If you are wanting proper html should go back to the server code and find where it gets changed to htmlentities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NgSanitize can't transform your string to html. You can achieve this using jQuery like:

```
return $('<div/>').html(text).text()
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbxfsk2e/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Maybe it isn't beautiful but it does the work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind as unsafe html, as follows:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
  <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="my_html | to_trusted"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If OP wants to display the content it has to be valid html first

Comment: Hi rageandqq, thanks for the reply. The ng-bind-html-unsafe is no more supported by angularjs after the 1.2.xxx version.